# Apiv2Error : Cannot sign manifest under that username

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, auth0

[image: apiv2 AUth0 error]
Getting error while running on expo react native app in local environment iam using `AUTH0` for authentication and use `authsession.redirecturl()`. we are using expo developer service which allow us to add any organization name in `app.json` owner and login with expo user account . but expo authsession not redirect me to on my project

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, apiv2 permission issie

Comment: Hey I'm having the same problem right now, could you please explain how did you fix the apiv2 permission issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you try removing the `owner : yourname` in the `app.json`, it should run.

Comment: It was a permission issue by ApiV2. it resolved